# Google drive java take in info from console

Tags: java, gradle

I'm trying to make a program that will take in the name for a folder I want to create within Google Drive, create that folder, and then upload a number of photos to the newly created folder.

I need to take input from the console in order to get the name for the new folder and can't find a way to do that since gradle or something seems to take up System.in so I'm not able to create a scanner object using System.in.

Any help is appreciated, just started with this project and I only just finished doing the tutorial/setup for google drive development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Getting user input thru a Gradle script is covered by the excellent MrHaKi blog:
http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2010/09/gradle-goodness-get-user-input-values.html

Basically you could have a pre-requisite task such as:

```
def foldername =''

task askFolderName << {
  def console = System.console()
  if (console) {
     foldername = console.readPassword('> Please enter the folder name: ')
  } else {
     logger.error "Cannot get console."
  }
}
```

Then in another task you can use the variable foldername